# Hash Table Code Explanation

Tags: ios, objective-c, hashtable

I found this implementation of a hash table written in objective-c. I can follow almost all of it, but am struggling to understand how exactly the -(id) init function works. This is the method in the HashTable.m file with 3 lines (I repasted it below right after the question). Could someone explain what exactly it is doing? I included some of the other relevant code although for the most part I think I can follow the rest. Despite that I'm unclear as to the specifics of the init method. Thanks

```
-(id)init
{
    self =[super init];
    self.othercontainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return self;
```

### }

HashTable.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HashTable : NSObject

@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray* othercontainer;

-(id)objectForKey:(NSString*)name;
-(void)setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString*)name;
-(id)init;


@end
```

HashTable.m

```
#import "HashTable.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation HashTable

-(id)init
{
    self =[super init];
    self.othercontainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return self;
}

-(id)objectForKey:(NSString*)name
{
    Person* tempPerson = nil;
    for (id item in self.othercontainer)
    {
        NSString* tempName = [((Person*)item) name];
        if ([tempName isEqualToString:name])
        {
            tempPerson = item;
            break;
        }

    }


    return tempPerson;
}

-(void)setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString*)name
{
    [self.othercontainer addObject:object];
}

@end
```

Part of ViewController.m

```
NSData *data;
NSFileHandle *fh;
NSString *inBoundFile = @"/Users/user/Desktop/names.txt";
NSString *fileString;

    fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:inBoundFile];

    data = [fh readDataToEndOfFile];
    fileString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *PersonArray = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    self.container = [[HashTable alloc]init];
    for (int x= 0; PersonArray.count > x ;x++) {
        NSArray* tempNameandAddress = [PersonArray[x] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        Person *personA = [[Person alloc]init]; //could be other ways of defining an instance of an object
        personA.name = tempNameandAddress[0];
        personA.address = tempNameandAddress[1];
        if ([self.container objectForKey:personA.name] == nil)
            [self.container setObject:personA forKey:personA.name];
        else
            NSLog(@"%@ already exists \n",personA.name);
    }
```

Comment: That code 1) does not implement anything like a hash table or even an associative array, and 2) is not very good. I would not use it as something to learn from.

Comment: Sorry - could you elaborate on that. I see some of the points made as to why the init method is poorly implemented but why did you feel the rest was not well written and/or doesn't represent a hash table or something like it.

Comment: A hash table is a data structure that can look up things up in constant time by hashing the key and using that hash as a lookup index to a bucket where the actual data is kept. This means it can store a huge number of values and it will still look them up quickly because it doesn't have to examine all the keys to find the one you want. This class not only doesn't hash keys or define buckets, it doesn't even *store* any keys. The `setObject:forKey:` implementation completely ignores the key argument. This "hash table" is just a confusing wrapper for an array search function.

Comment: Chuck knows his stuff. He's right. That's no hashtable by the way people usually mean. (But what's in a name?) but over all it's not a good example of Objective-C. I've seen worse but it's bad.

Comment: Basically **every single thing** about this code is wrong. I'd just forget it and move on.  Even the "init" is totally wrong -the mark of a clueless iOS programmer! Heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply an almost right common init. 
self is set to the object returned by the superclass init. 
Then they miss one proper step. 
The next step should be `if (self) { ...additional setup... }`
Basically only creating ivars/properties if self as returned from super init is not nil. 
If self is nil at that point you would normally just bypass additional code and go straight to return self. (Returning nil)

The next line is just creating the NSMutableArray ivar for the othercontainer property.

This is also not quite right. 
In init, this is when you should use the synthesized ivar directly. 
`_othercontainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Nothing special here.

Comment: What do you mean "almost right common" init? Do you mean this version of "init" is basically the same as the default init?

Comment: Yeah. It's almost the right way to do the common things you need to do. Common meaning fairly simple and normal vs uncommon like class clusters initialization.